# Remote debugging asp.net web application with external IP

Tags: asp.net, debugging, remote-debugging

I try to install remote debugger in my remote machine, and connect to it in my local computer, using visual studio 2012 for asp.net web application, windows8.
remote and local computers are not in the same network.
I installed the visual studio remote debugger in the remote machine and run it. it's instance name is:"SERVER-PC:4016"
In the local machine, I work on the project by ftp and in debug-attach to processor in qualifier field I enter the name in this format: external_ip:4016, and get an error:"The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer.."

p.s. I installed a local user in remote and local machine with the same name and password and run the relevant programs from this user name.

any ideas to solve my problem?
thank you!

Comment: What is the server OS? Looks like some comparability issue.

Comment: I don't use OS. My server is windows 8 with iis installed on it.

Comment: I meant the Operating system on server, which one is it? I experienced recently to connect to remote debugging tool running on Windows Server 2003 from Windows 7 and failed. I struggled to connect, but never succeeded. So I am thinking it might be some compatability issue between two machines.

Comment: Operating system in two computers is windows 8 (I don't use windows server, but only the basic edition with iis)